# Suppose that $d,\, m > 1$, and that $d|m$. Let $a,\,b \in\mathbb{ Z}$, prove that if $a \cong b (mod\,m)$ then $a \cong b (mod\,d)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The only sense I can make of this question is that $m = dq$ and $a \cong b (mod\,m)$ is the same as $as+mt=b$, or $as+(dq)t=b$. I feel as though proving that this holds since $m$ is just a multiple of $d$ is not enough.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why is it not enough?

Comment: $s$ doesn't happen to be 1 ?

Comment: My understanding of this is shaky at best, so maybe it is enough to prove this, but I don't see how $a \cong b$ for the modulo of some number still holds for a divisor of that number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $a \equiv b (\mod m)$, so $m$ divides $a-b$, by definition.

Now as $d$ divides $m$ and as $m$ divides $a-b$, so $d$ too divides $a-b$, and hence 
$a \equiv b (\mod d)$, as required.

Answer (score 0):

$$a\equiv b\bmod m\implies a=mx+b\implies a-b=mx$$
and 
$$a-b=mx\land m=de\implies a-b=dex$$